# Progressing from supinated to pronated chinups/pullups

Tags: pull-ups, chin-ups, grip

I've been getting better and better at doing chinups/pullups but I'm only able to do the "easy" ones, the ones with supinated grip, palms facing me.

I'm overweight but not enormous (185cm, 100+kg) and not known for my fitness, but it's improving.

Anyway the "hard" chinups/pullups with pronated grip, palms facing away, are so much harder for me that I can still barely do one even though I can do up to fifty "easy" ones if I spread out the sets.

Are there some techniques especially for progressing from "easy" to "hard" chinups? Anything that should be taken into account when overweight?

(I'm just using local outdoor gym equipment.

Comment: The other thing you can do is mix your grips. Do 5 with one hand in, the other out. Then switch and do 5 more.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea - I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Get a thick rubber band, and do them a lot.

I had the same problem as you, but I started doing crossfit, and there they are the standard movement. I did not really get that much stronger, but I just did them a lot, with a band to begin with. I think it is mainly a motor skill, where you need to practise activation other muscles.

Don't feel bad if it is hard, a body weight over +100 and doing around 50 pull ups is impressive!

Comment: They're only sets of five with walking breaks in between. But I impressed the hell out of myself too (-: